# Phpmyadmin Mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

I have debian server.

My phpmyadmin  & mysql through command line was earlier working well.
But suddenly i am getting this error while accessing phpmyadmin.

http://myserver/phpmyadmin

> 2003 - The server is not responding

And when i try to access through command line

```
mysql -u userid -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'userid'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And when i access through this

```
mysql -h ipaddress -u userid -p
```

it takes very long time to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can check or the 'bind-address' in my.ini and the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] value in config.inc.php (of phpMyAdmin) match. If not, change them or both to 'localhost' for only localhost access or the real ip address of the server for access from other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Does the mysql log say anything about this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mysql username and password in `config.inc.php` match what you've set in your mysql configuration file. If you can't get it working you may want to ask your web host.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons users generally get this error is because their firewall is not properly configured and does not allow an outgoing connection to ports like 3306 (This has happened to me more than once). Please check if that is the case with you.